# Entity Framework 3.5 + SQL Server Compact 3.5, slow performace because of cast

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm using VS2008, .NET 3,5, Entity Framework 3.5, Sql Server Compact 3.5 SP2. SQL SC 3.5 is accessed using EF, with Database first approach.

I'm using a simple query (linq and EF) that should use an existing compound index for columns StanjeId (tinyint) and ArtiklId (int).

```
var compQuery2 = from art in MobileDb.Artikl
                             where art.Stanje.StanjeId == (byte)1
                             && art.ArtiklId == tmp1
                             select art;

var quer1 = MobileDb.Artikl.Where(a => a.Stanje.StanjeId == (byte)1 && a.ArtiklId == tmp1);
```

The generated query using `(compQuery2 as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery).ToTraceString()` is:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[ArtiklGuid] AS [ArtiklGuid], 
.
.
[Extent1].[StanjeId] AS [StanjeId], 
[Extent1].[ZemljaPorijeklaDrzavaGuid] AS [ZemljaPorijeklaDrzavaGuid]
FROM [Artikl] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (1 = ( CAST( [Extent1].[StanjeId] AS int))) AND ([Extent1].[ArtiklId] = @p__linq__4)
```

The problem is that the generated query uses cast to int in the where part of the query for column StanjeId although StanjeId is of type tinyint (byte equivalent). That causes the SQL SC 3.5 not to use index seek, but a very slow table scan (table has `>1M` records).

How to get EF 3.5 to not use `CAST as int` in the where part the generated SQL query?

Comment: what is you used a `byte` variable assigned to 1 , `byte one=1` instead of `(byte)1` ?

Comment: WHERE part of the generated query is now:

WHERE (( CAST( [Extent1].[StanjeId] AS int)) = ( CAST( @p__linq__3 AS int))) AND ([Extent1].[ArtiklId] = @p__linq__4)

So is generally the same but now both StanjeId column and variable one are cast separately to int.

Comment: try this operator `Byte.CompareTo(Byte)` , `art.Stanje.StanjeId.CompareTo(one) == 0` , even if this explicitly casts , we will have to start looking into source code for diff methods/

Comment: Thanks Rameez :)
Your solution works great and removes the CAST from the generated SQL query. Why does art.Stanje.StanjeId == (byte)1 generate different code than art.Stanje.StanjeId.CompareTo(one) == 0 although logically it should be same?

Comment: Posted the answer below as it might help others , logically many things  look same in C# but when we look in the source code or ILDASM , we realize the difference. But your question is much more  important than my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this operator
 `Byte.CompareTo(Byte)` , `art.Stanje.StanjeId.CompareTo(one) == 0` ,
 even if this explicitly casts , we will have to start looking into source code for diff methods.